# How to add options to attribute format DetailView::widget at Yii2

Tags: php, yii, yii2

I format slug like the following

```
    [
        'attribute' => 'slug',
        'format' => 'url',
        'value' => "https://it-sharks.com/course/$model->slug",
    ]
```

How to add target='_blank' ?

Comment: Try adding `contentOptions => ['target' => '_blank']` after value. If not then create anchor tag as value option.

Answer (score 0):

I have used

```
'format' => ['url', 'options'=>['target' => '_blank']]
```